# Split comma separated values from one column to 2 rows in the results. MySQL

Tags: mysql

MySQL. Two columns, same table.
Column 1 has product_id
Column 2 has category_ids (sometimes 2 categories, so will look like 23,43)

How do i write a query to return a list of product_id, category_ids, with a seperate row if there is more than 1 category_id associated with a product_id.

i.e
**TABLE:**

```
product_id | category_ids 
100        | 200,300
101        | 201
```

**QUERY RESULT: Not trying to modify the table**

```
100 | 200
100 | 300
101 | 201
```

EDIT: (note) I don't actually wish to manipulate the table at all. Just doing a query in PHP, so i can use the data as needed.

Comment: Why are you saving category_ids comma seperated? It is not normalised form. Your desired result structure should be there.

Comment: This is almost an exact duplicate of this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10293861/split-comma-seperated-values-in-column-mysql/10294021#10294021

Comment: Another question that is an exact duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4890968/comma-seperated-value-seperation

Comment: And also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5342629/mysql-split-data-into-multiple-rows/5344071#5344071

Comment: i didn't create the table. just trying to get some data out. Checked out the link Gustav. No luck with a clear answer.

Comment: sorry didn't make it clear, i don't wish to chang ethe table at all. just running a query.

Comment: @jason3w unfortunately doesn't exist a reverse function of GROUP_CONCAT in mysql, would have been the one right for you ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your database table implementation seems bad designed, however in your case what you need would be a reverse function of GROUP_CONCAT, but unfortunately it doesn't exist in MySQL.

You have two viable solutions :

1. Change the way you store the data (allow duplicate on the `product_id` field and put multiple records with the same `product_id` for different `category_id`)
2. Manipulate the query result from within your application (you mentioned PHP in your question), in this case you have to split the `category_ids` column values and assemble a result set by your own

There is also a third solution that i have found that is like a trick (using a temporary table and a stored procedure), first of all you have to declare this stored procedure :

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE csv_Explode( sSepar VARCHAR(255), saVal TEXT )
body:
BEGIN

  DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS csv_Explode;
  CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE lib_Explode(
    `pos` int unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
    `val` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY  (`pos`)
  ) ENGINE=Memory COMMENT='Explode() results.';

  IF sSepar IS NULL OR saVal IS NULL THEN LEAVE body; END IF;

  SET @saTail = saVal;
  SET @iSeparLen = LENGTH( sSepar );

  create_layers:
  WHILE @saTail != '' DO

    # Get the next value
    SET @sHead = SUBSTRING_INDEX(@saTail, sSepar, 1);
    SET @saTail = SUBSTRING( @saTail, LENGTH(@sHead) + 1 + @iSeparLen );
    INSERT INTO lib_Explode SET val = @sHead;

  END WHILE;

END; $$
DELIMITER ;
```

Then you have to call the procedure passing the array in the column you want to explode :

```
CALL csv_explode(',', (SELECT category_ids FROM products WHERE product_id = 100));
```

After this you can show results in the temporary table in this way :

```
SELECT * FROM csv_explode;
```

And the result set will be :

```
+-----+-----+
| pos | val |
+-----+-----+
|   1 | 200 |
|   2 | 300 |
+-----+-----+
```

It could be a starting point for you ...

Comment: A dev achieved something similar for me before with this (but i don't know how to translate and use again): SELECT p.prodname, c.combinationid, CONCAT(o.voname),CONCAT(vovalue)
FROM isc_product_variation_combinations AS c
LEFT JOIN isc_product_variation_options AS o
ON find_in_set(o.voptionid, c.vcoptionids)
LEFT JOIN isc_products AS p
ON p.productid = c.vcproductid
WHERE c.vcproductid = 255

Comment: this was combining data from a few tables though. So thought it might be pretty easy with just one table.

Comment: The query you posted join two different table, is another thing. In that case you have a table with a single id and you join with that column using FIND_IN_SET function ...