# string search in MySQL Query

Tags: mysql, sql

My MySQL field having **skills field**(string) like,

```
1)php,mysql
2)java
3)java,c
```

I need to select the column with skills field condition. Condition may be Like,

```
skills="php"    // o/p => 1st column
or
skills = "mysql,c"   // o/p => 1st and 3rd column
```

How I can write Query.? Here im using PHP.

Comment: KarSho, any change you apply the First normal form and get your skill field in other table?

Comment: @medina ya, thanks for your !dea. But, i designed DB fully. Now i can't change.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to do it

```
SELECT *
  FROM table1
 WHERE skills LIKE '%mysql%' 
    OR skills LIKE '%c%'
```

**[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/31e16/1)**

*It would be much easier if you'd normalized your data*

Comment: My search condition may having 'n' content

Comment: @KarSho What do you mean by '...having 'n' content'?

Comment: @KarSHo What should happen when search condition is empty? Show all records or doesn't show anything?

Comment: @KarSho Well then in your php code if search condition is empty don't add `WHERE` clause, if it's not empty split it and build up your `WHERE` clause with as many OR's as you have keywords

Comment: potentially unlimited number of `OR` clauses?

Answer (score 1):

Use a procedure like this one:

[Split comma separated values from one column to 2 rows in the results. MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11100501/split-comma-separated-values-from-one-column-to-2-rows-in-the-results-mysql)

To split your csv skills field into a temp table with rows for each skill

Then do the same thing with your search parameters (which I assume is also csv string passed in)

Then simply apply a `JOIN` over the two results and get the `DISTICT` Id.

there are many solutions for splitting a comma separated string in MySQL (though it's not particularly good at this task)... if you can't properly normalize the data then you can't very well complain about inefficient query routines.