# How create split function in sqlite

Tags: android, sqlite

How create a function in SQLite that split comma separated values. Here is the [same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11100501/split-comma-separated-values-from-one-column-to-2-rows-in-the-results-mysql) but it is for MySQL.I want to do same thing in SQLite.

I tried this answer but I had no success.

Comment: Is it worth the effort? Wouldn't be easier to just store the data in a usable format?

Comment: http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.db.sqlite.general/67585

Comment: @RachelGallen  there is split(c2, ';') function,but it not inbuit function & there is no any additional info about it.

Comment: @user2251725 bah humbug thought i was onto something there