# return mysql column comma separated to object

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have some trouble here.. 
I hope somebody could help me.

so let me explain first

Lets say i have this table

```
idBarang | idAttribute | Value
----------------------------------
1        | 2           | A
2        | 2           | B
3        | 2           | B
4        | 2           | C,D
```

And then i have this Query Code

```
select * from relation_barang where idAttribute = '2' GROUP BY value  limit 0,20
```

My Problem Is, try too look the var_dump of my query result object

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  object(stdClass)#4 (5) {

    ["idBarang"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["idAttribute"]=>
    string(1) "2"
    ["value"]=>
    string(14) "A"

  }
    {
  [1]=>
  object(stdClass)#4 (5) {
    ["idBarang"]=>
    string(1) "2"
    ["idAttribute"]=>
    string(1) "2"
    ["value"]=>
    string(1) "B"

  }


[1]=>
      object(stdClass)#4 (5) {
        ["idBarang"]=>
        string(1) "4"
        ["idAttribute"]=>
        string(1) "2"
        ["value"]=>
        string(1) "C,D"

      }

    }
```

And what wanted is something Like this

```
array(2) {
      [0]=>
      object(stdClass)#4 (5) {

        ["idBarang"]=>
        string(1) "1"
        ["idAttribute"]=>
        string(1) "2"
        ["value"]=>
        string(14) "A"

      }
        {
      [1]=>
      object(stdClass)#4 (5) {
        ["idBarang"]=>
        string(1) "2"
        ["idAttribute"]=>
        string(1) "2"
        ["value"]=>
        string(1) "B"

      }
 [2]=>
      object(stdClass)#4 (5) {
        ["idBarang"]=>
        string(1) "4"
        ["idAttribute"]=>
        string(1) "2"
        ["value"]=>
        string(1) "C"

      }
[3]=>
      object(stdClass)#4 (5) {
        ["idBarang"]=>
        string(1) "4"
        ["idAttribute"]=>
        string(1) "2"
        ["value"]=>
        string(1) "D"

      }


    }
```

I try to searching on google but cant find the solution

how to do that? did anyone knows how to do that? im really confused here..
anyone experts help me please,,, thanks

Comment: With the query you are running, you should get no results, given the table you provided. Please explain what you want in words.

Comment: My bads.. iwrite the wrong query.. now i fix my information.. can you help me?

Comment: You shouldn't store values like that. What if you need to remove/edit a value? Think about redesigning your table.

Comment: I only want to edit the table output, look at the 3rd value of the table ("C,D"), i would like to separate that string and make it as object to.. so the object array will become 4.. do you got me?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11100501/split-comma-separated-values-from-one-column-to-2-rows-in-the-results-mysql

Comment: Ahh, I see what you mean. You want to split the `C,D` into separate array indexes with an SQL query.  Unfortunately, SQL doesn't work like that.  You should design your database differently, what you want to do is awkward since the data isn't separated properly.  Probably it can be done, but there must be a better way to access the values.