# MySQL GROUP BY each comma separated value

Tags: mysql, sql

Before anyone comments, I did not design this database with comma separated values :)
I have spent time trying to find the answer but all I could find was GROUP_CONCAT() which seemed to do the opposite of what I wanted.

I would like to GROUP BY each of the values within the comma separated value field.

```
SELECT round(avg(DATEDIFF( dateClosed , dateAded ) * 1.0), 2) AS avg, department
FROM tickets GROUP BY assignedto
```

the assignedto field is the comma separated value field

```
row1 54,69,555
row2 54,75,555
row3 75,555
```

DESIRED OUTPUT: an average rounded figure for each value in assignedto field grouped.

EDIT - TRYING TO TAKE THIS TO THE NEXT LEVEL:
I want to include the ticket answer table to get the first response for that ticket, use its datetime field to work out the average response time for each user.

```
SELECT a.id as theuser, round(avg(DATEDIFF( ta.dateAded , t.dateAded ) * 1.0), 2) as avg
FROM tickets t join
     mdl_user a
     on find_in_set(a.id, t.assignedto) > 0
INNER JOIN (SELECT MIN(ta.dateAded) as started FROM ticketanswer GROUP BY ta.ticketId) ta ON t.id = ta.ticketId
GROUP BY a.id ORDER BY avg ASC
```

Comment: Your question is not so clear. Try to post on some sample data of your tickets table and the desired output data please.

Comment: Convert the csv's ('assingnto') back into rows? [11100501/split-comma-separated-values-from-one-column-to-2-rows-in-the-results-mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11100501/split-comma-separated-values-from-one-column-to-2-rows-in-the-results-mysql)

Comment: Create a table with tickets ID and single values. If tickets hold a modification time, also that one. [For splitting a string see here](http://blog.fedecarg.com/2009/02/22/mysql-split-string-function/). Keep it simple.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yuck.  You can do this, assuming you know the maximum number of assignments.  Here is an approach:

```
select substring_index(substring_index(assignedto, ',', n.n), ',', -1) as assignedto,
       round(avg(DATEDIFF( dateClosed , dateAded ) * 1.0), 2) as avg
from tickets t join
     (select 1 as n union all select 2 union all select 3)
     on length(assignedto) - length(replace(assignedto, ',', '')) < n.n
group by substring_index(substring_index(assignedto, ',', n.n), ',', -1);
```

Or, an easier way if you have a list of assigned values, say in an `AssignedTo` table:

```
select a.assignedto, round(avg(DATEDIFF( dateClosed , dateAded ) * 1.0), 2) as avg
from tickets t join
     assignedto a
     on find_in_set(a.assignedto, t.assignedto) > 0
group by a.assignedto;
```

I'm sorry you have to deal with this malformed database structure.

Comment: Brilliant, thank you very much. I used the second one as I have a user table to JOIN it to

Comment: @Codded . . . You should ask that as another question, not as an edit to an already answered question.

Comment: thanks, please could you take a look; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27296432/mysql-join-by-select-earliest-datetime/27296649#27296649