# MySQL JOIN by SELECT earliest DATETIME

Tags: mysql, sql

This query groups tickets by who they are assigned to and works out the average rounded number of days the ticket has taken to be closed.

```
SELECT a.id as theuser, round(avg(DATEDIFF( ta.dateClosed, t.dateAded ) * 1.0), 2) as avg
FROM tickets t join
     mdl_user a
     on find_in_set(a.id, t.assignedto) > 0
GROUP BY a.id ORDER BY avg ASC
```

I would now like to JOIN the ticketanswer table to find out the average time for first response.
The ticket could have multiple answers so i just want to get the first one.
Therefore I have tried to change the query to include this with no avail. Could anyone shed a light as to what im doing wrong?

```
SELECT a.id as theuser, round(avg(DATEDIFF( ta.dateAded , t.dateAded ) * 1.0), 2) as avg
FROM tickets t join
     mdl_user a
     on find_in_set(a.id, t.assignedto) > 0
INNER JOIN (SELECT MIN(ta.dateAded) as started FROM ticketanswer GROUP BY ta.ticketId) ta ON t.id = ta.ticketId
GROUP BY a.id ORDER BY avg ASC
```

Answer (score 1):

Made some slight modifications to your query.

```
SELECT a.id as theuser, round(avg(DATEDIFF( ta.dateAded , t.dateAded ) * 1.0), 2) as avg
FROM tickets t join
 mdl_user a
 on find_in_set(a.id, t.assignedto) > 0
INNER JOIN (SELECT ticketid, MIN(dateAded) as started FROM ticketanswer GROUP BY ticketId) ta ON t.id = ta.ticketId
GROUP BY a.id ORDER BY avg ASC
```